# how to make child class deserialize without type property in Jackson while type specified in parent class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a service that receives my parent interface as input in order to receive different types as input.
interface is defined as below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Person.class, name = "person"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Employee.class , name = "employee")
})
public interface TestInterface {
}
```

and i have a service that gets TestInterface as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/convert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Person test(@RequestBody TestInterface object){}
```

this service must get json like below and works just file with type property:

```
 {"@type":"person","name":null,"family":"fami"}
```

the problem is when i have a service that receives the child class directly and i don't want to specify type property.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/convertPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Person test(@RequestBody Person object){}
```

in this example when i don't send type property i get (missing type id property) exception. is there any way to make it work without type id?
i already tried the below config but it didn't solve the problem:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-missing-external-type-id-property=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved the problem by putting @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE) on top of child class. with this annotation child class can work independently without type and also parent interface will work fine with types.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
public class Person implements TestInterface{
}
```